# how do I select a SF2 font preset in fluidsynth from command line?

Tags: audio, music

I use fluidsynth to play SF2 piano soundfonts, some of which have presets (like 000:000 Bright or 000:001 Mellow, etc).
I usually run fluidsynth with the command:

```
fluidsynth --server --no-shell --audio-driver=alsa -o audio.period-size=128 /path/to/soundfont.sf2
```

and was wondering if there is some command, flag, or option that would allow me to select a specific preset from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn´t quite figure out how to do this from the command line, but I found a workaround.
Let's say I have a soundfont nicepiano.sf2 with presets 0 bright 1 mellow 2 dark and I want to play the dark preset.
I can:

A) create the file /home/username/.fluidsynth/dark.conf

B) in this file put the code:

```
 load /path/to/nicepiano.sf2
 load 0 2
```

C) start fluidsynth with the code:

```
 fluidsynth -f /home/user/.fluidsynth/dark.conf
```

D) obviously connect fluidsynth, in my case with aconnect

Let's say that, once fluidsynth is running, I want to switch to preset bright, I can do so with the command:

```
 prog 0 0
```

from fluidsynth command line, or 0 1 if I want to play the mellow preset.